# If every variable and class objects are determined at compile time, how do you handle dynamic data from games?

Tags: c++, class

I'm learning the basics of C++, but one thing that confuses me right now is that how a program accommodates to include new information that pops up during the course of a program.

Say you have a very crude bank program. 
And you have a class called "Bank" with a few variables:

```
account holder's name
account holder's number
account holder's balance
```

Then you construct a class object and assign the name, maybe like this:

```
Bank x("John", 10001000, 100) //name = John, accnt number = 10001000, balance = 100
```

So now, I'm confused as to what you must do to store information for the next customer with different name. If I just repeat the code in a loop, I will be overwriting John's information. How do I keep both? And how do I keep adding more customer information?

Comment: You use `new` to allocate objects dynamically.

Comment: I guess you haven't gotten to the chapter on pointers yet.

Comment: If I use Bank* newcustomer = new Bank("John",10001000,100), and do another object instantiation with, Bank* newcustomer = new Bank("Mary",20001000,100), doesn't John's information get overwritten?

Comment: @niamleeson yes. That is why you should create two different objects (and delete them when you're done!). Like so:

`Bank *newCustomer = new Bank("John", 10001000, 100);` and `Bank *anotherCustomer = new Bank("Mary", 20001000, 100);`

Comment: @niamleeson the most general answer is that you will soon [learn about containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).  That link will show containers that are included in the C++ standard library, but that is merely a starting point.

Comment: What if you don't know how many customers there will be? Is there a way to store all the future customer information? I would have to have Bank* uniquevariable = new Bank() for every single customer in the code, and that doesn't seem practical...

Comment: Yes, you will learn about both loops and containers soon enough. Dynamic allocation using `std::vector` and a `for` loop will address most of your questions/concerns.

Comment: You **don't** use `new` to allocate objects. You don't use pointers. That's what you did in the 1980s. C++ has improved a lot since then.

Comment: In the real world, such data is stored in databases. You just load the database records that you need for each operation, which is usually a small subset of the whole collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `vector` of `Bank` objects?

```
vector<Bank> gameData;
//Loop
    Bank b = ConstructBank();
    gameData.push_back(b);
```

Comment: also: `gameData.emplace_back("John", 10001000, 100));`